# How do I include the dependent entities of an inherited entity with entity framework core that uses Discriminator column?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Given following models with inheritance:

```
public class Credential { ... }

public class LocationCredential: Credential {
    ...
    public long LocationId {get; set;}
    public Location Location {get; set;}
}

public class EducationCredential: Credential {
    ...
    public long SchoolId {get; set;}
    public Location School {get; set;}
}

public class School { ... }
public class Location { ... }
```

Entity framework core creates only one `Credentials` table with a `Discriminator` column to identify the inherited class in the db.

How can I include the dependent entities when querying the credentials? 
I would like to do something like this:

```
var cred = await context.Credentials
    .Where( c => c.CredentialId == 123)
    .Include(c => c.Location) // cannot do these beacause they are not 
    .Include(c => c.School)  // properties of Credential class
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I don't want to do separate queries for each inherited class and then return the non-null one. Don't want these:

```
 var cred = await context.EducationCredentials
        .Where( c => c.CredentialId == 123)
        .Include(c => c.School)  
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
   if (cred == null) {
       // try same thing with LocationCredentials
   }
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this; I still don't like it because it requires two calls to the db;

```
        var cred =  await _context.Credentials
            .Where(c => c.CredentialId == credentialId)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (cred.GetType() == typeof(LocationCredential)) {
            return await _context.LocationCredentials
                .Where(e => e.CredentialId == credentialId)
                .Include(e => e.Location)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NotMapped]
```

public class LocationCredential: Credential 
{

```
...
public long LocationId {get; set;}
public Location Location {get; set;}
```

}

use [NotMapped] Attributes on your model like this.

Comment: [NotMapped] is used to not create a model / column in database via entity framework. That is not what I am trying to do at all.

Answer (score 0):

this is old thread, but i found nothing how to solve this problem and decided to write possible solution here . may be it helps somebody sometime
for the short answer fastforward to cast in ThenInclude

model

```
public enum InventoryType {ANY, MONEY, STOCK}
[Table ("Inventory")]
public class cInventory 
{
    ...
    public InventoryType InventoryType {get;set;}
    public List<cInventoryVersion>Versions {get;set}
    ....
}

[Table("InventoryVersions")]
public abstract class cInventoryVersion
{
   ......
   //descriminator
   public InventoryType InvType {get;set;}
}

public class cIMVersion : cInventoryVersion
{
   public List<cIMItems> Items {get;set;}
}

public class cISVersion : cInventoryVersion
{
   public List<cISItems> Items {get;set;}
}

[Table("IMItems")]
public class cIMItems 
{
...
}

Table("ISItems")]
public class cISItems
{
...
}
```

context configuration

```
  public virtual DbSet<cInventory> tblInventories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<cInventoryVersion> tblInventoryVersions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<cISVersion> tblISVersions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<cIMVersion> tblIMVersions { get; set; }
```

onModelCreating

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<cInventoryVersion>(e =>
            {
                e.HasDiscriminator<InventoryType>(e => e.InvType)

                                .HasValue<cISVersion>(InventoryType.STOCK)
                                .HasValue<cIMVersion>(InventoryType.MONEY);
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<cISVersion>(e =>
            {
                e.HasMany(e => e.Items).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<cIMVersion>(e =>
            {
                e.HasMany(e => e.Items).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<cInventory>(e =>
            {
                e.HasMany(e => e.Versions).WithOne().OnDelete(deleteBehavior: DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
```

Include correct items with descriminator

```
 public void LoadData(int invid)
        {
            _inventory = _ourDB.tblInventories
                                .Include(i => i.Org)
                                .Include(i => i.CreatedBy)
                                .Include(i => i.ClosedBy)
                                .Include(i => i.Versions).ThenInclude(i => (i as cIMVersion).Items)
                                .Include(i => i.FinishedBy).FirstOrDefault();

   
            
        }
```